# How to list all files in a FTP server?

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-2010, indy, indy10

I want List all files in a FTP server for Indexing(Main Dir and Sub Directories).

How can I get a full list of the files accessible in the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indy has a `TIdFTP` component, which has a `List()` method and a `DirectoryListing` property.  Call `List()` and then loop through the resulting `DirectoryListing` as needed.  Each item in the `DirectoryListing` will tell you whether it is a file or a subfolder.  If you need to index an entire system, you will have to call `List()` in a recursive loop for each subfolder.

Something to keep in mind - there are literally hundreds of platform-specific directory listing formats still being used by FTP servers on the Internet today.  The `LIST` command outlined in the original FTP specification, [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), did not define any kind of formatting to be used for listings, so systems were free to use whatever they wanted to use, and they did do exactly that over the years.  Windows and Unix formats are common, but they are not required.  A formal listing format was not defined until [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659) in the `MLSD` extension to FTP, which replaces the old `LIST` command (`TIdFTP.List()` does use `MLSD` if the server supports it).

I mention this because `TIdFTP` in Indy 10 uses a plugin system to support many of these different listing formats.  Each format is implemented in a separate `IdFTPListParse...` unit in Indy.  By default, only the `NLST` and `MLSD` formats are always enabled.  For any other listing format you want to support, you need to include the appropriate `IdFTPListParse...` unit into your `uses` clause in order for `TIdFTP` to recognize it.  For example, `IdFTPListParseUnix` and `IdFTPListParseWindows`.  Alternatively, there is a `IdAllFTPListParsers` unit that enables all of the available parsers.  When you call `TIdFTP.List()`, the `TIdFTP.DirFormat` property will be set to the name of the parser that was used to parse the raw listing data.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP protocol is documented in [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt). The command to list files is called `LIST` as documented in section 4.1.3.

Comment: Of course it can. It works just as well in the sub directories.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, It just can List current dirrectory. In this case I want to write a function which can List all directories. for example List command in ftp is the same as "dir" command in windows command prompt, I want to write a function similar "dir /s" for finding all sub directories in a ftp.

Comment: Go ahead and write such a function then. All you need is `LIST` and a spot of recursion.